# Comparing data from two SQL Server databases using build-in tools?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can I compare the data from two SQL Server 2008 RT databases using built-in tools in SQL Management Studio or do I need to look for some third-party tool to do this?

I've used "the Google" but only seem to get information about third-party tools.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of global compare, or just a few tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use Except operator or checksum like i explain in this [post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/01/05/The-simplest-way-to-delete-duplicates-and-compare-two-result.aspx).
Just note that the CheckSum method can provide duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is big, you may want to look into [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you need very sophisticated comparisons you can use Open Source DiffKit:

www.diffkit.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx). For the most part they work pretty well but they don't have many features and tend to show some limitations on complex tasks. 
Third party tools like [xSQL Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql) give you a huge amount of control over the comparison and synchronization process, so I suggest you take a look at those as well.

Dislcaimer: I'm affiliated to xSQL